# Updating slider value in a label in swift

Tags: swift

I have a slider view with a label. I need to update the label value as slider moves. Slider is working and I'm able to get the slider value in logs. But the label value is updationg only afer reloading the table view or corresponding cell. This is causing flickering affect.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
{
    rangeSlider.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.addSubview(rangeSlider)
    rangeSlider.tag = indexPath.row
    rangeSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PresentedViewController.rangeSliderValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showSliderValue), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "slidervalue"), object: nil)

    {
        cell.currentMaximumValue.text = self.upperSliderText
        cell.currentMinimumValue.text = self.LowerSliderText
    }
    else{
        let b:String = String(format:"%f", appDelegate.priceslidermaximumValue)
        let c:String = String(format:"%f", appDelegate.pricesliderminimumValue)
        cell.currentMaximumValue.text = b
        cell.currentMinimumValue.text = c
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Are you having slider in tableViewCell ?

Comment: yes inside a table view cell

Comment: Show code of `cellForRowAt` that will give us idea how you are populating data in tableView

Comment: Im not getting where to include the code for updating the label....is it in the table view cell or in CELLforRow at index path  delegate?

Comment: You need to use dat source array with your tableView that maintain the slider's current value for each cell

Comment: in the above code self.upperSliderText has the latest slider value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply.
To resolve the flickering effect on reloading the cell I have used following line.

```
tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: indexPath.section),
                         with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you need to change in your code.

First, in your `cellForRowAt` method, if you get your cell object by `dequeueReusableCell`, you need to be careful when doing `addSubview` action. So your cell object is just a reusable cell that may already have a slider on it. If you don't clean all views before adding subview, after you scroll up and down for a while, your cell will be full of sliders and may crash. I recommend you to add this slider in a custom table view cell from storyboard.

Second, do not use `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver`. Since `cellForRow` get called for each cell that is prepared for display, you are adding observer so many times.

**So here is the answer**

Make an array to store your slider values for each cell

```
var sliderValues = [10, 20, 30, 40]
```

In your `cellForRow`, just add the listener like

```
cell.textField.text = sliderValues[indexPath.row]
cell.slider.tag = indexPath.row // Use tag to see which cell your slider is located
cell.slider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(sliderValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Then in your function to work with the listener

```
func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider){
    sliderValues[sender.tag] = sender.value
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```