# Connecting slider to label

Tags: ios, swift

How can I connect the position of slider's value with label's position? I want, that when slider change its value, the label move with slider's value too. please help me. I can't write this code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide anything (context, code, …) that may be helpful for the community to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating slider value in a label in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668549/updating-slider-value-in-a-label-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this inside the slider change value action

```
 // calculate current space available for movement 
 let factor = ( self.view.frame.width - self.label.frame.width ) / maxSliderValue
 // apply the change according to slider value assuming in x axis 
 self.label.frame.origin.x = factor * slider.value
```